# Move semantics for a conversion operator

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

What's the syntax for a movable conversion operator?

I have a wrapper that wraps around `obj`, which has an `obj` conversion operator:

```
class wrap {
public:
   operator obj() { ... }
private:
   obj data_;
};
```

How can I find out whether `data_` should be copied or moved?

Comment: How could you move `data_` into an `std::string` anyway? If `data_` were an `std::string` also, this question would make a lot more sense.

Comment: @ildjarn the question is about move semantics on conversion operator, not particularly about char* or std::string.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. You just happened to pick the worst possible data type as your first example. ;-]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax for that would be something like this:

```
class wrap {
public:
   operator obj() const & { ... }   //Copy from me.
   operator obj() && { ... }  //Move from me.
private:
   obj data_;
};
```

The first version will be called when the second version cannot be called (ie: the `wrap` instance being converted is not a temporary or there is no explicit use of `std::move`).

Note that Visual Studio didn't implement this aspect of r-value references in VS11.

Comment: `const&` might even be desirable as usually copy operations are `const`.

Comment: I think `operator obj const & () const &` makes more sense, if the return value is a subobject. There is no need to copy. Likewise `operator obj && () &&` would eliminate a move-construction, even if it's expected to be O(1).

Comment: Can you specify which version of VS doesn't implement this? I think you are talking about VS10. Do you know if VS11(last release candidate) does already have the standard version?

Comment: @Klaim: Neither of them support it.

Comment: Can you confirm that [the single `&` is only for symmetry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21861190/560648)?