# What does the single ampersand after the parameter list of a member function declaration mean?

Tags: c++, c++11

From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758664/move-semantics-for-a-conversion-operator/10758725#10758725).

```
class wrap {
public:
   operator obj() const & { ... }   //Copy from me.
   operator obj() && { ... }  //Move from me.
private:
   obj data_;
};
```

I know the `&&` means that the member will be invoked when the object is an rvalue reference. But what does the single ampersand mean? How is it different than without the ampersand?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It means the member will be invoked when the object is an lvalue reference.

> `[C++11: 9.3.1/5]:` A non-static member function may be declared with a *ref-qualifier* (8.3.5); see 13.3.1.
>
> `[C++11: 13.3.1/4]:` For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object parameter is
>
> - “lvalue reference to *cv* `X`” for functions declared without a *ref-qualifier* or with the `&` *ref-qualifier*
> - “rvalue reference to *cv* `X`” for functions declared with the `&&` ref-qualifier
>
> where `X` is the class of which the function is a member and *cv* is the *cv-qualification* on the member function declaration. *[..]*
>
> *(and some more rules that I can't find)*

Without a *ref-qualifier*, the function can always be invoked, regardless of the value category of the expression through which you're invoking it:

```
struct foo
{
    void bar() {}
    void bar1() & {}
    void bar2() && {}
};

int main()
{
    foo().bar();  // (always fine)
    foo().bar1(); // doesn't compile because bar1() requires an lvalue
    foo().bar2();
    
    foo f;
    f.bar();      // (always fine)
    f.bar1();
    f.bar2();     // doesn't compile because bar2() requires an rvalue
}
```

#### [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6c39d2e81f0acfa6) <sup>(thanks Praetorian)</sup>

Comment: Yeah, but isn't that the default?

Comment: I'm not confident enough to post an answer because I haven't played much with ref-qualifiers, but I think leaving it out allows the member function to be invoked on an rvalue or lvalue, while adding it restricts invocation to the corresponding value category. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ae326e4f2a8ae31

Comment: @clin18 You cannot overload a function with a ref-qualifier with a function that's without it. You either have both or none.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You can quote 13.1/2, third bullet.

Comment: Dang it, missed out on some repz! I'm glad to see you modified my nonsense comments in the example :)

Comment: @jrok: Could do - not sure I want to veer into overloading, though >.< Still, feel free to add :)

Comment: @user2005303: No.

Answer (score 32):

> But what does the single ampersand mean?

The function can *only* be called on an lvalue, not on an rvalue.

> How is it different than without the ampersand?

Without a ref-qualifier you can invoke the function on an lvalue *or* an rvalue.

With a ref-qualifier you can only call the function on the corresponding value category.

Answer (score 11):

A function without a ref-qualifier can be called for both rvalue and lvalues. A function with a `&&` ref-qualifier can only be called for rvalues. A function with a `&` ref-qualifier can only be called for lvalues.

```
class No { void foo(); };
class L { void foo() &; };
class R { void foo() &&; };

No().foo(); // valid
No no; no.foo(); // valid
L().foo(); // invalid
L l; l.foo(); // valid
R().foo(); // valid
R r; r.foo(); // invalid
```

Unfortunately, I can only find this rule in 5.5/6, which applies only to pointer-to-member dereference expressions. I know it applies otherwise too.

Furthermore, you cannot overload on ref-qualifier vs no ref-qualifier, see 13.1/2 bullet 3. You can overload on `&` vs `&&`.

(And due to my fruitless search of the standard, LRiO's answer now has all that info too.)

Comment: I gave up finding a decent quote for it too >.< +1

Comment: [over.match.funcs] p4 determines the implicit obejct parameter, which affects which (if any) overload is viable

Comment: Right, by p4, neither `&` nor no qualifier match rvalues. p5 then contains a special exception that no qualifier may bind to an rvalue.