# Const reference qualifier on a member function

Tags: c++, reference, member-functions, const-reference

I have seen in an anwser there:
[Is returning by rvalue reference more efficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116641/is-returning-by-rvalue-reference-more-efficient)

The member function definition:

```
Beta_ab const& getAB() const& { return ab; }
```

I am familiar with the *cv-qualifier* (`const`) on member functions, but not `const&`.

What does the last `const&` mean?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21861148/420683

Comment: Note that the accepted answer's example is a non-const `&` qualifier, whereas the question is about a `const&` qualifier. The example `kitten{}.pet();` would actually compile if `pet` were qualified as `void pet() const&;`. To forbid this we'd need to add the additional line: `void pet() const&& = delete;`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `&` is a *ref-qualifier*. Ref-qualifiers are new in C++11 and not yet supported in all compilers, so you don't see them that often currently. It specifies that this function can only be called on lvalues (and not on rvalues):

```
#include <iostream>

class kitten
{
private:
    int mood = 0;

public:
    void pet() &
    {
        mood += 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    kitten cat{};
    cat.pet(); // ok

    kitten{}.pet(); // not ok: cannot pet a temporary kitten
}
```

---

Combined with the cv-qualifier `const`, it means that you can only call this member function on lvalues, and those may be const.

Comment: You might add that this is a new feature in C++11, not yet supported by all compilers, and that you're not likely to see it in existing code (yet).

Comment: The relevance of this construction is that it forbids things like `Beta_ab const & danger = Beta_ab().getAB();`

Comment: OK, I see. So if supported by the compiler, this should be set on every const member function returning a const reference to a member variable? I have lots of these and occasionally had bugs related to using them on a rvalue.

Comment: You should remove the first half of the answer! Most people know that already, and this would make the important part of your answer visible without scrolling down. First reaction by reading is : ughh ok I already know what a const modifier does on a member function...

Comment: Good point. Removing that part.

Comment: Arghhh I'm with gcc 4.8.0 and only 4.8.1 supports this...  http://isocpp.org/blog/2013/05/gcc-4.8.1-released-c11-feature-complete

Comment: I agree also with your other point: When returning a *reference* to some object bound to the lifetime of your own object, you get the usual lifetime issues. Under some circumstances, that's acceptable, but per default, it should be qualified with an lvalue-ref. (That's btw what Kerrek was pointing out.)

Comment: @dyp : The question is now more clear also!

Answer (score 10):

We know that in this code...

```
Beta_ab const& getAB() const { return ab; }
                       ^^^^^
```

The highlighted `const` means that the member function may be called upon a `const` object. A member function can always be called upon a non-`const` object regardless of the function's cv-qualification.

So in this code...

```
Beta_ab const& getAB() const & { return ab; }
                             ^
```

We should expect that the highlighted `&` also says something about what kinds of objects this member function is allowed to be called upon. We would be correct; in C++11, this says that the member function may only be called upon lvalues.

```
Beta_ab const& getAB() const& { return ab; }
Beta_ab &&     getAB() &&     { return ab; }
```

In the above example, the first overload is invoked on lvalues, and the second overload is invoked on non-`const` rvalues. Similar to the following more familiar example, with qualifiers applied to ordinary function parameters:

```
void setAB(AB const& _ab) { ab = _ab; }
void setAB(AB &&     _ab) { ab = std::move(_ab); }
```

It works slightly differently for ordinary parameters though, as in this example, the first overload would accept an rvalue if the second overload were removed.