# What is the difference between making a member function of a class const vs const reference in C++?

Tags: c++, constants

What is the difference between marking a function `const` vs `const&` of a class?

For example:

```cpp
class abc {
Private:
    std::string str;
Public:
    const std::string& foo(const int&) const&;
    const std::string& bar(const int&) const;
}
```

Is there any difference between them? When would you use one over the other?

Comment: You seldom need reference qualified methods. So stick to the normal `const`

Comment: See [Const reference qualifier on a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011532/const-reference-qualifier-on-a-member-function).

Comment: Thank You. I didn't know about ref-qualifiers. And I guess the question is wrong cause I mistook it for const reference. Is there anything else that I need to know regarding this?

Comment: Also should I delete my question or how should I edit or improve it for others to refer?