# Why doesn't this std::string C++ code give compile-time error?

Tags: c++, string, move-semantics

I have the following snippet:

```
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string a, b, c;
    a + b = c;
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't this C++ code give compile-time error? This is probably because of the way `std::string::operator+` has been implemented but then my question is: why was it implemented this way? In what cases is such behaviour needed?

Comment: why would it give a compile error? a+B returns a valid string object. as for use? it may not be usable

Comment: @DavidHaim OP probably expects it to fail by for the same reasons it would fail it `a, b, c` were `int`.

Comment: Can someone list a valid use case for it?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Any valid use case would involve a constructor, destructor or `operator=` with side effects; in any other case, that expression behaves *AS A* noop, imho.

Comment: @PaoloM: I meant that for `std::string`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign to temporary objects. There is no rule preventing this.

If you don't want a member function to be invoked on a temporary (on an *r-value*, more generally), you can use a [*ref-qualifier*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21861190/2508150) in the function declaration.

But as you can see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D), `std::string::operator=` does not have a *ref-qualified* version.

I don't think that the Standard Committee allowed this behavior with a definite goal in mind; I guess the rationale behind this choice is to impose to the programmer the less rules as possible and let him to find a useful application, if any can exists.

Comment: I guess the problem, is how temporary is temporary.  The result for `class X a,b,c; a+b = c;` may be desirable where the temporaries result in some modified global state being updated.

Comment: Assignment operator with side effects sounds like a huge antipattern to me

Comment: @DarkWanderer I don't know whether *throwing* can be seen as a side-effect, but for sure an assignment operator can throw.

Comment: It can, but if this is used, then the one who writes that code will be *relying* on that throw, which is a bit of code smell too.

Comment: @DarkWanderer It would, indeed