# Overload accessor member function that _might_ return a reference

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm getting an error that these forms cannot be overloaded.

But I thought something like this is supposed to be the new best practice, to improve safety when returning a reference to a member:  allow it only when calling on an lvalue.  Why does this not compile?  What is the overloading rule this doesn't like, and what is the right way to write this new idiom?

```
struct S {
    string m;
    string& get_m() & { return m; }
    string get_m() const { return m; }
};
```

see also on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/qb188W).

I suppose having the `const` qualifier is overly restrictive since I want that form on any non-lvalue even if it wasn't const, but writing `string get_m() &&` gives an error when I call it on a const lvalue (non-temporary).

Answer (score 1):

You can refine your overloads further to handle those cases appropriately:

```
string &       get_m() &       { return m; }             // called on non-const l-values
string const & get_m() const & { return m; }             // called on const l-values
string         get_m() &&      { return std::move(m); }  // called on r-values
```

Comment: huh? What's that syntax of && after function name and braces?

Comment: @Zeks It's a ref-qualifier. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861148/what-does-the-single-ampersand-after-the-parameter-list-of-a-member-function-dec

Comment: huh... I didn't realize those were a thing. thanks.

Comment: So what's the rule in the standard that says the original set is "not allowed"?

Comment: @JDługosz It's not a single rule exactly. The ambiguity in the original overload set falls out of the rules for overload resolution.