# const &, const &&, &, && after a function?

Tags: c++, class

I'm looking through some internal infrastructure code at the moment and I saw some functions defined as such:

```
// func_name is a class member function

some_return_type func_name() & {
  // definition
}

some_return_type func_name() && {
  // definition
}

some_return_type func_name() const& {
  // definition
}

some_return_type func_name() const&& {
  // definition
}
```

I know having `const` after a class member function name means it won't modify immutable member variables defined in the class. But what does `&`, `&&`, `const &`, and `const &&` variants here mean?

Comment: @Frank Do you know what the name of this C++ feature is called? I wanted to Google to do some reading on it but not sure what the name is to google for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "rvalue reference for \*this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610571/what-is-rvalue-reference-for-this)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861148/

Answer (score 9):

Using `self` as the object the method is called on:

1. `self` must match `Type&`:

   ```
   some_return_type func_name() &;
   ```
2. `self` must match `Type&&` (and will also match `Type const&&` and `Type const&`):

   ```
   some_return_type func_name() &&;
   ```
3. `self` must match `Type const&&` (and will also match `Type const&`):

   ```
   some_return_type func_name() const&&;
   ```
4. `self` must match `Type const&`:

   ```
   some_return_type func_name() const&;
   ```

As you can see, it would be simpler to understand if C++ had had references from the beginning, and chose `self`-references instead of `this`-pointers.

[Cppreference.com on ref-qualified member-functions](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#ref-qualified_member_functions).

Comment: Can you reference the standard that speaks of these? What are they called?

Comment: I am also curious to know what the generic name of this feature is. I'd like to read up more on it

Comment: It won't get better than ref-qualified member-functions (with a side-order of cv-qualified member-functions).