# C++ why declare member function const

Tags: c++, member-functions

I understand that specifying a member function "const" allows us to call it from a const object, but why do we have to explicitly write "const" next to the member function? Why can't the compiler figure out that

```cpp
int getFoo() {
  return m_foo;
}
```

is indeed "const" for all intents and purposes?

Comment: What if you want to return a reference when in a non-const context?

Comment: Because you may have a `const` and non `const` version of that function doing different things. The keyword present or not changes the signature of the member functions.

Comment: The `const` lets you tell the compiler what your intention actually is. If the compiler just tried to deduce "Oh, this _could be_ marked `const`, I'll let it be callable from `const` objects", then you would have functions whose `const`-ness changes if you change the internal implementation. Right now if you make a change to a `const` member function that would make it non-`const`, the compiler will stop you and force you to figure out what should happen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Then I can add it when required, but in simple cases like a getter it's annoying to have to specify it

Comment: @Jojolatino who defines, what's the _"simple case"_?? It just depends on specific use-cases to be expressed in explicit syntax.

Comment: @Jojolatino "*but why do we have to explicitly write "const" next to the member function?*" - because C++ is (largely) a statically-typed language, and a compiled language. You have to state your intentions explicitly to the compiler. It can't always infer const-ness based on context alone. Things get even more fun when you start [ref-qualifying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861148/) your member methods, not just const-qualifying them.

Comment: `int getFoo()` tells me *this member function changes the logical state of the object* (perhaps due to caching or lazy initialization or incrementing a use counter).  `int getFoo() const` tells me *this member function does not change the logical state of the object*.  I believe modern C++ expects the `const` version to be an even stronger guarantee, in regards to thread safety.

Comment: Realize that the `const` keyword provides useful information to the CALLER (not just the implementation restrictions).  Technically, the method could be "logically const" by modifying `mutable` members all over the place.  The client just needs to know, from their standpoint, that the method will not change the state of the object (even if it technically internally is non-const - the Caller just needs to know it's `const` from the Caller's perspective.)

Comment: @franji1 why does the caller care? If the function is "implicitly" const and they try to modify a const object then their program won't compile, they don't need to know that beforehand I think

Comment: I see what you are asking.  C++ does not have *implicitly `const`*.  When I had a chance to chat with Bjarne once, and was listing my grievances with C++, he stopped me short and said "If you don't like C++, you are free to make your own language.  I did."

Answer (score 8):

Because C++ allows declarations to be in different places to definitions.

If all you have is

```
class Bar {
    int m_foo;
public:
    int getFoo();
};
```

can you safely call `getFoo` on a `const Bar`?